# GTK theme settings not being respected

Tags: linux, colors, themes, dwm

I am currently running DWM and would like to have all my applications be dark themed. Since DWM doesn't have any control panel or anything like that I tried changing the config file on `$HOME/.config/gtk-4.0/settings.ini` for both GTK4 and 3. I put in the line

```
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=true
```

However, no app goes to dark mode by default. I tried changing the theme using the color scheme command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme prefer-dark
```

I did that then ran Firefox from that terminal but nothing changed. What else could I do in this situation?

Comment: I have the same issue.  I have tried both of those and also `$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Adwaita-dark'`

Comment: The latter used to work for me.  It stopped working around the time I switched from Fedora 36 to Fedora 37 minimal.

Comment: `GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark pavucontrol` does open the volume control with a dark theme

Comment: Try in `settings.ini` to add `gtk-theme-name` and `gtk-icon-themename`. See [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jvFpYaSoPo).

Comment: Thank you. Adding that in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` (and `4.0`) does not work for me. Also, I'm looking for a solution that changes the theme on-the-fly, without having to restart apps.

Comment: It might be hard to change the theme in a running application that wasn't programmed for it. There exists `lookandfeeltool` for some environments.

Comment: I've seen Firefox and most of the apps I use change on-the-fly. But sometime around when I switched from Fedora 36 to Fedora 37 minimal, this ability went away.

Answer (score 0):

Following [Automatically switch color schemed in ... GTK applications](https://felix-kling.de/blog/2021/linux-toggle-dark-mode.html) by [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) worked for me.

Specifically, I am running `xsettingsd` with the following in `~/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf`:

```
Net/ThemeName "Adwaita-dark"
```

Then, to set the theme to light, I remove `-dark`, which can be done programmatically as so:

```
grep -q 'Net/ThemeName ".*-dark"' ~/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf && \
( sed -e 's#\(Net/ThemeName ".*\)-dark"#\1"#' ~/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf && \
  pkill -HUP xsettingsd )
```

And to set the theme back to dark, I add `-dark` back in:

```
grep -q 'Net/ThemeName ".*-dark"' ~/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf || \
( sed -e 's#\(Net/ThemeName ".*\)"#\1-dark"#' ~/.config/xsettingsd/xsettingsd.conf && \
  pkill -HUP xsettingsd )
```

Firefox and other apps now change their theme on the fly.

This is a little more complicated than what Felix uses, but allows you to change the theme from Adwaita to any other theme that has a corresponding dark mode.